# Check vs. check up on

Tags: differences, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between "check" and "check up on"? Let us say my friend Kate is in her room a little bit sick. I am going to her bedroom to see if she is OK, and tell other friends of mine:

1. I need to check Kate.
2. I need to check up on Kate.

Tell me please if there any difference, and if there is none, as I assume, what is "up on" there for?

Comment: Pick #2. #1 is talking about examining Kate, something she may prefer to have a doctor do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lawrence stated, *check* would be incorrect as it implies an examination.

> **1** Examine (something) in order to determine its accuracy, quality, or condition, or to detect the presence of something.
>   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/check

To "check up on" would be idiomatically correct, but it might carry the connotation of being sceptical or suspicious of what she might be up to. So you may want to simply just "check on".

*"I need to check on Kate."*